# 3.5 Python Interactive Quiz App Answer Check Not Working

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm trying to have only one defined function for this

> WELCOME TO Your Test
>
> Word 1/5: Potato How many consanants does the word contain?
>
> 3
>
> Correct!
>
> Word 2/5: Potato How many vowels does the word contain?
>
> 1
>
> Correct!
>
> Word 3/5: Name How many vowels does the word contain
>
> 5
>
> Incorrect! Correct answer 4
>
> Word 4/5: YES How many letters does the word contain? 3 Correct!
>
> Word 5/5: Day
>
> What is letter 3 of the word?
>
> Y
>
> Correct!
>
> Game Over. Your Score is 4/5

@Niemmi Like this this?
    import random
    import string

```
def consonant_count(word):
    word = word.lower()
    return len([x for x in word if x in consonants])

def vowel_count(word):
    word = word.lower()
    return len([x for x in word if x in vowels])

def prompt_letter_count(word):
    correct = word_map[word]['letters']
    ans = input('How many letters does "{}" contain?'.format(word))
    return check(int(ans), correct)

def prompt_vowel_count(word):
    correct = word_map[word]['vowels']
    ans = input('How many vowels does "{}" contain?'.format(word))
    return check(int(ans), correct)

def prompt_consonant_count(word):
    correct = word_map[word]['consonants']
    ans = input('How many consonants does "{}" contain?'.format(word))
    return check(int(ans), correct)

def prompt_random_letter(word):
    n = random.randint(0, len(word))
    correct = word[n-1]
    ans = input('What is letter {} of "{}"?'.format(n, word))
    return check(int(ans).lower(), correct.lower())

def check(ans, correct):
    if ans == correct:
        return prompt_correct()
    return prompt_incorrect()


def prompt_correct():
    print('That is correct! :)')
    return 1

def prompt_incorrect():
    print('That is incorrect :(')
    return 0

def next_question(word):
    q_type = input_map[random.randint(1, 4)]
    return q_type(word)

vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
consonants = [x for x in string.ascii_lowercase if x not in vowels]
quizWords = ['WOMBAT', 'COMPUTER', 'BOOKS', 'DAY', 'NIGHT', 'HOUR', 'POTATO', 'HUGE', 'TINY', 'GOOD', 'BAD', 'YES', 'NO', 'HOUSE', 'QUESTION', 'BALLOON', 'CAT', 'DUCK', 'KOOKARBURRA', 'POSTER', 'TELEVISION', 'PRINCE', 'RHYTHM', 'SUDDENLY', 'SNOW', 'MAGNET', 'TOWEL', 'WALKING', 'SPEAKER', 'UNCHARACTERISTICALLY']
word_map = {x:{'consonants':consonant_count(x), 'vowels':vowel_count(x), 'letters':len(x)} for x in quizWords}
input_map = {1:prompt_letter_count, 2:prompt_vowel_count, 3:prompt_consonant_count, 4:prompt_random_letter}

def start_quiz(number_questions):
    current_question = 0
    correct_questions = 0
    if number_questions > len(quizWords):
        number_questions = len(quizWords)
    sample_questions = random.sample(quizWords, number_questions)
    print('WELCOME TO YOUR QUIZ')
    print ('---------------------')
    for x in sample_questions:
        print ("Question {}/{}:".format(current_question+1,  number_questions))
        correct_questions += next_question(x)
        print ('---------------------')
        current_question += 1
    print ('Congragulations on completing your quiz!')
    print ("    Score {}/{}:".format(correct_questions , number_questions))
    try_again = input('Would you like to try again? (y/n)').lower()
    if try_again == 'y' or try_again == 'yes':
        start_quiz(number_questions)

start_quiz(4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're expecting [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) to return you a `int` which it doesn't do on Python 3. Python 3 `input` works the same way as [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#raw_input) on Python 2 returning a string that you need to convert to other type yourself. You should be able to fix your code by doing the conversions at the required places and switching all `raw_input` calls to `input` since there's no `raw_input` on Python 3.

Example:

```
def prompt_letter_count(word):
    correct = word_map[word]['letters']
    ans = input('How many letters does "{}" contain?'.format(word))
    return check(int(ans), correct) # instead of check(ans, correct)
```

Comment: that can be checked by debugging function `check`: add `print(repr(ans))` and `print(repr(correct))` to see one is a string and the other isn't

Comment: @Niemmi 
I think I made the correct changes, am I on the right rack? See above

Comment: @SamMay Otherwise looks ok but at `prompt_random_letter` you don't want to convert the answer to `int` since you're comparing strings against each other.

Comment: @NiemmiCause I tried using it and the letter count still doesn't seem to want to work. Wait false alarm figured it out all good thanks mate :)

Comment: @SamMay If the correct answer type is `int` as in all the "How many xxx does something contain?" questions you need to convert the user input to `int`. Then if the correct answer type is `str` as in "What's the xth letter of word y?" then there's no conversion needed since the input is `str` already.